# ONVIF : Can we connect to NVR just same as ONVIF IP Camera in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, onvif

I have successfully connected my android device with IP Camera through ONVIF with IP of particular camera, How can i list out all the cameras that connected to a single NVR?

I want to make an application like https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mcu.iVMS&hl=en.